# shell string comparison is not working

Tags: macos, shell

I'm trying to test the energy saver startup and shutdown settings via shell only the my string comparison always responds with no

here is my code

```
#!/bin/sh

pmset repeat shutdown MTWRFSU 19:00:00 wakeorpoweron MTWRF 07:00:00

test=`pmset -g sched`
schd="Repeating power events: wakepoweron at 7:00AM weekdays only shutdown at 7:00PM every day"
echo $schd;
echo $test;
if [ '$test' = '$schd' ]; then 
    echo "yes"
else 
    echo "no"
fi
```

what am i doing wrong here  ?

added this which returns yes as expected

```
test2="Repeating power events: wakepoweron at 7:00AM weekdays only shutdown at 7:00PM every day"
schd2="Repeating power events: wakepoweron at 7:00AM weekdays only shutdown at 7:00PM every day"

if [ "$test2" = "$schd2" ]; then 
    echo "yes"
else 
    echo "no"
fi
```

I suspect there are hidden characters in the output of my test command as everything else seems to be in order is there some way to confirm and eradicate them, if that is in fact the problem ?

Comment: @chepner i changed it to the double quotes because I had already tried with the double quotes and still did not have success thus yes there is still a question since it still doesn't work with double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think $test might have extra characters, try testing that $test *contains* $schd:

```
case "$test" in
*"$schd"*) echo yes ;;
*) echo no ;;
esac
```

Try changing

```
echo $schd;
echo $test;
```

to

```
echo "schd=>$schd<"
echo "test=>$test<"
```

Comment: ok that was it!!! even though i had tried putting the returns in  due to indentation it was coming up incorrect but this allow me to see the problem

Answer (score 2):

Variable references are not resolved within single quotes; use double quotes instead:

```
if [ "$test" = "$schd" ]; then...
```

Also, note that the above test won't work if either `$schd` or `$test` is resolved to the empty string. A common trick to work around this is as follows:

```
if [ x"$test" = x"$schd" ]; then...
```

Comment: The `x` trick is only needed if the strings aren't double-quoted (although it also doesn't *hurt* anything...)

Comment: i had already tried with double quotes but changed them anyhow and then tried your workaround as well

Comment: is it possible that hidden characters such as \n \r are causing a comparison issue